# insert using someModel::create($request->all()) laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel

i am new in laravel, 
i am using ajax to insert some data to model "student",

```
$('#form-insert').on('submit', function(e) {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).serialize();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        var method = $(this).attr('method');
        // console.log(method);
        $.ajax({
            type: method,
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataTy: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

and this is my view form

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add new Student</h4>
      </div>
      <form class="" action="{{route('store')}}" method="POST" id="form-insert">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastname">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender">Gender</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="gender">
                <option value="">Choose Gender</option>
                <option value="laki-laki">Laki-laki</option>
                <option value="perempuan">Perempuan</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large float-left btn-info">submit</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large float-right btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">close</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is my model student

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class student extends Model
{
    protected $fillabel = ['firstname','lastname','gender'];

}
```

and this my route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
Route::prefix('ajax')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/','AjaxController@index')->name('readdata');
    Route::get('/readstudent','AjaxController@readdata')->name('readdata');
    Route::post('/store','AjaxController@store')->name('store');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

and this my controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Response;
use App\student;

class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
      return view('ajax.index');
    }
    public function readdata(){
      $data = student::all();
      // return response($data);
      return view('ajax.studentlist',compact('data'));
    }

     function store(Request $request){

      if($request->ajax()){

        $student = student::create($request->all());
        return response($student);
      }

    }
}
```

, i try this controller code for insert data but it don't work, and give me error 500 ,i dont why.. but when i change contoller code like this

```
function store(Request $request){

  if($request->ajax()){
    $student = new student;
    $student->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $student->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $student->gender = $request->gender;
    $student->save();

    // $student = student::create($request->all());
    return response($student);
  }

}
```

it work fine, i just want to know what wrong with the previous code..

Comment: Post your code not images

Comment: I think we cannot have same names for 2 different routes. In your routes with prefix ajax, check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$fillabel should be written `$fillable` in your model